# Search for name, email and created_at in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I added search in a single field for name, email and created_at. I am able to get the searched result in my params. e.g., If I search for swapna then my params are like: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"search"=>"swapna"}}.`

I had added the query like: `Message.includes(:user).where("users.name LIKE ? OR messages.to LIKE ? OR messages.created_at LIKE ? " ,"%#{@query}%", "%#{@query}%", "%#{@query}%")`

But after adding the search for date in my query I am getting the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone ~~ unknown
LINE 1: ...essages.to LIKE '%swapna%' OR messages.created_at LIKE '%swa
```

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
"created_at = ?", @query
```

instead of

```
"created_at like ?", "%#{@query}%"
```

because I think you cant query a date with like

Comment: Its also not working and I think it is not the correct way too.

Comment: try "created_at = ?", "#{@query}" or "created_at = ?", Date.parse("#{@query}")

Comment: also make sure that you include the time because its created_at field

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, I hope it works for you.
Since **joins** uses **lazy loading** there might be slight performance issue.

@query = params[:search]
  @messages = Message.joins(:user).where("user.name LIKE ? OR messages.to LIKE ? OR messages.created_at LIKE ?" ,"%#{@query}%", "%#{@query}%", "%#{@query}%")

Comment: Will change joins to includes. But still the issue is coming for the date search. I guess there is some format issue in date.

Answer (score 0):

the created_at field is a datetime field so searching 'like' and '=' would not work. so you need to use span of time to find specific date with any time

.Try this and I hope it works.

```
#@query.to_date + 1.days returns next day with time 00:00:00

Message.includes(:user).where("users.name LIKE ? OR messages.to LIKE ? OR "messages.created_at >= ? and messages.created_at < ?", "%#{@query}%", "%#{@query}%", @query.to_date, @query.to_date+1.days)
```